# Getting Query syntax error when trying to use inner join

Tags: hibernate, hql

Im getting a  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException in my query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update Room as r "
            + "inner join Booking as b "
            + "on r.roomId = b.room.roomId "
            + "set r.roomAvailable = true "
            + "where b.checkOutDate < NOW()");
```

full error:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "set", found 'inner' near line 1, column 55 [update com.websystique.springsecurity.model.Room as r inner join com.websystique.springsecurity.model.Booking as b on r.roomId = b.room.roomId set r.roomAvailable = true where b.checkOutDate < NOW()]

the query is working fine in mysql workbench... so is this possible in anyway here in code or not?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: *the query is working fine in mysql workbench*: mysql workbench executes SQL queries. session.createQuery expects an HQL query. Those are two different languages.

Comment: you need to use createSqlQuery insted of createQuery

Comment: @mvlaicevich Thanks buddy!

Comment: @john you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a query with a subselect instead of a join. Rewrite your query and it will work.